# Backpressure in a Spring DeferredResult + Akka actors application

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, akka, backpressure, deferred-result

I am thinking of using a chain of Akka workers to model a workflow inside a DeferredResult based Spring MVC web application. Essentially the controller will return a *DeferredResult* and the actors in the chain will work to populate a *CompletableFuture* which feeds the DeferredResult when completed.

What I am not able to figure out is:
* Will Akka exert back-pressure if this setup takes on too much load.
* If so, how can I detect that this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [Alpakka's Spring Web connector](https://developer.lightbend.com/docs/alpakka/current/spring-web.html), which allows integration of [Akka Streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-introduction.html) in a Spring Web application. Akka Streams provides backpressure as part of its adherence to the [reactive streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/) specification, and the connector allows the exposure of streams as HTTP endpoints in a Spring application. An example from the Alpakka documentation:

```java
@RestController
public class SampleController {

  @RequestMapping("/")
  public Source<String, NotUsed> index() {
    return
      Source.repeat("Hello world!")
        .intersperse("\n")
        .take(10);
  }
}
```

In your case, you could model your workflow as a stream.

The Akka team recently published a [blog post](https://akka.io/blog/news/2017/10/23/native-akka-streams-in-spring-web-and-boot-via-alpakka) about this connector.

Comment: Requirements changed and the project got shelved :) but I tried this out for a PoC and it seemed to work. Thanks for the pointer.